# MySQL minusing sum amount on the same ID from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

Okay first of all this might be a very complicated question, i'm trying to explain as clear as i can so that you guys can help me at its finest.

it's about the database of the software i develop for production planning section. First of all i'm stating the tables that i'm using in this command, there're 4 tables you need to know : **ceramic_transaction(which means there are ceramic and transaction tables) and report table**

---

`Ceramic_transaction` consist of 3 columns : **Ceramic_id, transaction_id, amount**

while `report` consist of : **report_id, ceramic_id, transaction_id, amount**

The thing is `ceramic_transaction` table's amount is the one that is needed by the client, and the amount on `report` table is what has been done by the workers.

i will then give you sample data for the test

`Ceramic_transaction`

```
 1. CT0046 T201600022 6 
 2. CT0047 T201600022 6
```

`report`

```
 1. R0001 CT0046 T201600022 3
 2. R0001 CT0046 T201600022 2
```

The problem is, i'm trying to minus the total amount that workers have done AND show the rest that needs to be done (i have done that), yet the others ceramic that is available in the report table won't show up ( the one that has not even worked ), in this case it's `CT0047`

Code sample:

```
SELECT CT.CERAMIC_ID , IF(CT.CERAMIC_ID = R.CERAMIC_ID, CT.AMOUNT - SUM(R.AMOUNT), CT.AMOUNT) as needs
FROM CERAMIC_TRANSACTION CT, REPORT R
WHERE CT.CERAMIC_ID = R.CERAMIC_ID AND CT.TRANSACTION_ID = R.TRANSACTION_ID GROUP BY CT.CERAMIC_ID
```

`RESULT`:

```
CT0046  1
```

`DESIRED RESULTS`:

```
CT0046  1

CT0047  6
```

**obviously because CT0047 is not done any of them**

**EDIT 1**

if there are other data inside Ceramic_transaction that the **transaction_ID** is not the same, it shouldn't be shown, so that's why my code is where `CT.transaction_ID = r.transaction_ID`, i'm trying to show the **Ceramic** that is not done yet by the workers on every `transaction_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to use a left join:

```
SELECT CT.CERAMIC_ID ,
       IF(CT.CERAMIC_ID = R.CERAMIC_ID, CT.AMOUNT - SUM(R.AMOUNT), CT.AMOUNT) as needs
FROM CERAMIC_TRANSACTION CT
LEFT OUTER JOIN REPORT R
ON (CT.CERAMIC_ID = R.CERAMIC_ID
   AND CT.TRANSACTION_ID = R.TRANSACTION_ID)
WHERE CT.transaction_id = 'T201600022' 
GROUP BY CT.CERAMIC_ID
```

This problem comes from using explicit join syntax, you should always avoid doing that(Table1,table2,...). Use the proper syntax of joins [that you can read about here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: it shows CT0046 and CT0047, but it also shows OTHERS, i mean other ceramics that is in Ceramic_transaction, ALL of them other than 46 and 47

Comment: Isn't that what you want? you said you want those who haven't been worked on yet. @RobertWilliam

Comment: Yeah but on the same Transaction_ID , i mean to click it on the dataGridview exactly as the transaction_ID, sorry i forgot to state that

Comment: @RobertWilliam Try it now.